# Class methods are not at the same address for both Parent and Child Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

i try at the bellow code (for educational reasons) to implement this logic with class methods. What i observe is that, (a) the func1 inside the NO_CALCULATE list is not at the same address as func1 of the Parent class. (b) The type of the elements inside Calculate list, are class method objects and not methods as at CALCULATE LIST. The result of this, my code evaluates as TRUE the if statement and calculates all the functions. Can someone explain me the (a),(b) and the overall behaviour as well?
**(reminder:I know how to implement that logic without class methods
but i try to do it that way for educational purposes)**

```
class Parent:
    @classmethod
    def func1(cls):
        print("hello func1")

    @classmethod
    def func2(cls):
        print("hello func2")

    @classmethod
    def func3(cls):
        print("hello func3")

    CALCULATE = [func1, func2, func3]
    NO_CALCULATE = []

    @classmethod
    def calculate_kpis(cls):
        for func in cls.CALCULATE:
            if func not in cls.NO_CALCULATE:
                func.__get__(cls)()

class Child(Parent):
    NO_CALCULATE = [Parent.func1]  #REMOVE ΤΗIS CALCULATION FROM CHILD

if __name__ == "__main__":
     p1 = Child()
     p1.calculate_kpis()
```

Comment: When you write `Parent.func1` or `Child.func1` the methods are bound to the specified class. Bound methods aren't at the same location as the method itself.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your answer! Can you explain me more thoroughly with the picture of the memory? I iterate to NO_CALCULATE which explicitly refers toy Parent.func1 , why there is no connection between two func1 of the classes

Comment: Methods are implemented as [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) and they're generated dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "address"? In Python we don't use object addresses at all.

There is, yes, an object ID, that as an implementation detail is the object pointer, (its address), but it is not usable as such from pure Python code.

So, assuming you are seeing the ID's: both classmethods and ordinary instance methods are dynamic objects, and they are created new when they are retrieved. The underlying function-object that is used for each method is the same object, always - but when we use a `Parent.func3` expression to retrieve the `func3` classmethod, Python triggers an underlying mechanism (see write ups for "Python's descriptor protocol", if you want to dig on that), which creates a new "method object" which is bound to the target class (or instance, in the case of normal methods). This object is not cached - that is also an implementation detail, so each time it is retrieved, a new one is created. One can check these assertions by either comparing their ID, or using the `is` operator.

Pasting directly from my interactive interpreter:

```
In [56]: class Parent:
    ...:     @classmethod
    ...:     def func1(cls):
    ...:         ...
    ...: 

In [57]: class Child(Parent):
    ...:     pass
    ...: 

In [58]: id(Parent.func1)
Out[58]: 139726686424000

In [59]: id(Parent.func1)
Out[59]: 139726691941312

In [60]: id(Child.func1)
Out[60]: 139727237259712

In [61]: Parent.func1 is Parent.func1
Out[61]: False

In [62]: Parent.func1.__func__ is Child.func1.__func_
    ...: _
Out[62]: True
```

As you can see, methods are always different objects, but the underlying function, reachable through the `__func__` attribute in a method, is the same.

This explains why your logic for "No_CALCULATE" does not work: methods lack a custom equality comparison, and then Python defaults to identity (`is`): and the class method in the `NO_CALCULATE` list is does not have the same identity as the one retrieved dynamically inside the `calculate_kpis` for loop.

The remedy would be to compare by the `__func__` attribute of each method, or rather, by the method name, as  a string: that will prevent methods defined in other super-classes (such as mixins or intermediary classes) from running as well:

```
...
class Parent:
    ...


    @classmethod
    def calculate_kpis(cls):
        for func in cls.CALCULATE:
            # compares using the method/function name, as string.
            if func.__name__ not in cls.NO_CALCULATE: 
                # No need to use the descriptor inner method
                #  `__get__`: the first parameter can be filled
                # in as a positional parameter normally
                func(cls)  
                # (rather than func.__get__(cls)())

...

class Child(Parent):
    NO_CALCULATE = ["func1"]  #List by method name, as string.

...
```

Comment: Look at the code. What he means by different addresses is that they aren't considered equal by `func in cls.NO_CALCULATE`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that. I added further explanation on how it can be done now.

Comment: @jsbueno thank you so much for your detailed answer. I think i understand. Every time i call a method e.g MYCLASS.method, a method object is creating which has inside the initial function, but the object it selfe is different and is created dynamically everytime i call the method with that way. Am i correct ?

Comment: yes, that is it. It is a deliberate choice of the language of not caching method objects - they are low cost to create, and handle such a cache would be a complex thing - for too little gain, I guess

Comment: The object is created when the method is referenced, with the "." like in `MyClass.method` - not when it is called (via the actual calling with parenthesis`()`. It can be stored in a local variable and reused several times, and that is a known micro-optimization in some cases.